# How to provide functions via context in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React UI kit and want to get some functionality to it. I also have some functionality without the UI. Both are working separately, but I cannot manage to work together due to the error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'authenticate' of
> 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

I have an account object which is the context provider (Accounts.js, shortened for brevity):

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'
import Pool from 'UserPool'

const AccountContext = createContext()

const Account = (props) => {
  const getSession = async () =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...
    })

  const authenticate = async (Email, Password) =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...
    })

  const logout = () => {
    const user = Pool.getCurrentUser()
    if (user) {
      user.signOut()
    }
  }

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider
      value={{
        authenticate,
        getSession,
        logout
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { Account, AccountContext }
```

And I have SignIn.js Component which throws the error (also shortened):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import validate from 'validate.js';
import { AccountContext } from 'Accounts.js';


const SignIn = props => {
  const { history } = props;

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const { authenticate, getSession } = useContext(AccountContext);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    isValid: false,
    values: {},
    touched: {},
    errors: {}
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const errors = validate(formState.values, schema);

    setFormState(formState => ({
      ...formState,
      isValid: errors ? false : true,
      errors: errors || {}
    }));

    getSession()
      .then(session => {
        console.log('Session:', session);
        setStatus(true);
      });

  }, [formState.values]);
  

  const handleSignIn = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    authenticate(formState.values.email, formState.values.password)
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Logged in!', data);
        //setStatus(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Failed to login!', err);
        //setStatus(false);
      })
    history.push('/');
  };

  
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      
    </div>
  );
};

SignIn.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.object
};

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

I guess something is wrong with the Accounts.js because the SignIn.js cannot use the authenticate or getSession functions. I need those in the context because other components will render differently when a user is signed in and getSession exactly retrieves this info. Accounts.js is calling against AWS Cognito. I understand how to use variables or states in context but functions seem to work differently. How do I define the functions in Accounts.js to add them to the context so that I can use them in other components as well?

Comment: What does your component hierarchy look like? `<SignIn>` must be a descendant of an `<Account>` in order to have access to the context.

Comment: Since you mean `Account` as a context provider, don't need to make it a component. Just export the context as well as the object so your `App.js` import it then put `<AccountContext.Provider>` around main app. This makes sense cause user authentication context should be global and accessible to all components without worrying about context inheritance (like making sure your component should be inside the provider in your case)

Comment: Thx, @SonNguyen, I tried it so that I now have `<AccountContext.Provider value={Account}>` wrapped around the main app. Now the error message is _TypeError: getSession is not a function_. Do I have to define the consumer in SignIn.js?

Comment: @adcgn Export Account as the value itself, not as a component. Define `Account` as `{
        authenticate: async () => {...},
        getSession: async () => {...},,
        logout: () => async {...}
      }`

Comment: I also have the same approach in my application. Can you make sure that you wrap the `SignIn` component inside `Account` which is Provider. You just have to wrap it like:   `<Account><SignIn></Account>`

Comment: @SonNguyen thanks. That now works within the SignIn.js. But I cannot access it other parts. Don't I just need to import Account and AccountContext?

Comment: @adcgn In all parts including SignIn.js you just need to import `AccountContext`. No need for `Account`

Comment: Thanks that now works. It took me the whole day to understand this concept. So you saved another one for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried similar approach in my application.

As per your code, everything is looking fine. The error you have mentioned can be because of wrapping `SignIn` component wrongly in Provider i.e `Account`.

> Try wrapping `SignIn` Component inside `Account` Provider like below:

```js
Import {Account} from './Accounts.js' // Path of Account.js file

<Account> // Account act as Provider as per your code
  <SignIn />
  ...
</Account>
```

Rest of your code seems fine.

Comment: Because Account.js holds the user information, it makes sense to wrap it in the App.js. Then the context is available throughout the app with `AccountContext`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `SignIn` component must be wrapped inside `Account` Provider. Did it work, If not can you tell me what error you are facing..

Comment: I defined `Account` as an object within the `AccountContext`. The `AccountContext` is wrapped in the `App.js` making the context available in the whole app. Within the `SignIn` component I just need to use the context `const { authenticate } = useContext(AccountContext);` to enable authentication. This is working.